# How can I make outlook 2010 read from my other folders in Hotmail?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have configured my outlook 2010 using Pop3 but I just see the folder Inbox. There are other folders in my Hotmail account but I don't see them? How can I add them to read the emails?

Comment: Try connecting via IMAP and see if you have the same results

Comment: I tried it but there will be a problem sending/receiving emails.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Outlook Connector for Hotmail instead of POP3.  Works very nicely.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx

Comment: I tried that but there is a problem with it. The Sending/Receiving emails hangs and does not come to end so it is difficult to keep up to date with emails.